# Duplicate existing UIView in a ScrollView programmatically? (Storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard

i use Storyboard and i want to duplicate and add an existing UIView (with all "childs" like UILabels) progammatically to a ScrollView. So first i created a custom UIView-Class for that View *(EventView)* in which i initialize the new text for the UILabels by identifying them with their Tags. 
Now i want to add these EventViews to a Scrollview like this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 320*10);
UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
     CGRect rC = CGRectMake(0.0, 320*i, 320, 320);

    EventView *dV = [[EventView alloc] initWithFrame:rC];
   [dV inWithEvent:allEvents[i]];//Strings for the UILabels
    [theView addSubview:dV];

}

theScrollView.contentSize = rect.size;
[theScrollView addSubview:theView];
}
```

Is there a better (and working) solution? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to duplicate a view or ui object there is a method i learned here

```
 NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: viewToBeDuplicated];

 UIView * newView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
```

now you can do whatever you want with the new view.

Comment: It probably doesn't archive/unarchive "everything" (or I probably should RTFM) because for example it doesn't "bring back" the UIView in the same "configuration" I archived it. I have a CAGradientLayer among other things and it seems to me the "newView" (or archivedData) has the View being fully Opaque.

Comment: What this does is just: 1. archive an existing view, 2. unarchive the archived view as new view.